# Dog kicking all four paws when playing?

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have a 7 month old Chihuahua male and whenever he's on our bed he kicks all four paws when you are playing with him. We have a female that is his sister but she was born 3 litters before him and only does it when she poops outside.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by kicking all four paws?

Comment: It's normal, It's just an act of playing.